# What is an ONA?

Tags: terminology

Searching through MAL and other anime sites, I found an unfamiliar type of anime. What is an "ONA"? Is it different from a OVA?

[image: types of anime on MAL]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ONA and OVA are completely different in terms of their target markets.

An Original Net Animation (ONA) is an anime that is directly released onto the Internet<sup>(1)</sup> while an Original Video Animation (OVA) is an animated film or series made specially for release in home-video formats.<sup>(2)</sup>

> The term ONA was first coined by the creators of Lingerie Fighter Papillon Rose and Anime News Network decided to adopt it for use in the encyclpedia since
>
> 1. There was no other word to describe this new format of anime.
> 2. We felt "ONA" was an original and appropriate denomination.<sup>(3)</sup>

> Many ONAs are designed as side stories to an existing franchise, or are simply promotional vehicles. The ONA Hitotsubu ni Kawaranu Ai wo Komete, for instance, was created to celebrate the 100th anniversary of Morinaga Milk Caramel candy. HALO Legends tells several standalone stories in the universe of the HALO video game.<sup>(4)</sup>

Some examples of ONAs:

- [Eve no Jikan](http://myanimelist.net/anime/3167/Eve_no_Jikan) (before it was made into a movie)
- [Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Lite](http://myanimelist.net/anime/15687/Chuunibyou_demo_Koi_ga_Shitai!_Lite)
- [Yamada-kun to 7-nin no Majo](http://myanimelist.net/anime/20359/Yamada-kun_to_7-nin_no_Majo)
- [There She Is!!](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6505/There_She_Is!!)
- [Kyousou Giga](http://myanimelist.net/anime/10893/Kyousou_Giga) (the first one)
- [Hetalia Axis Powers](http://myanimelist.net/anime/5060/Hetalia_Axis_Powers)

**NOTE:**
Just a different name for the same show, some of anime site name it web.

Sources:

- [(1) - Wikipedia: "Original net animation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_net_animation)
- [(2) - Wikipedia: "Original video animation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_video_animation)
- [(3) - Anime News Network: "Original Net Anime (ONA)"](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/lexicon.php?id=37)
- [(4) - anime.about.com: "ONA (Original Net Animation)"](http://anime.about.com/od/animeglossary/g/Ona.htm)

Comment: Wasn't [Azumanga Daioh](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1593/Azumanga_Web_Daioh) originally a web episode after which the series started?

Comment: @user1306322 From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azumanga_Daioh#Anime): Azumanga Web Daioh, a shorter original net animation made available for paid streaming on chara-ani.com beginning from December 28, 2000, then offered as a paid download for a limited time. So yes, it's an ONA before the TV series started.